# How can I find all repositories that have a push mirror setup in Gitea?

Tags: gitea

I have a personal Gitea instance (1.16.9) that has over 130 repos, spread across multiple owners (user and organizations).

For some number of them I have push mirroring setup to GitHub, but have recently needed to change my personal access token. *Pull* mirror failures show in the admin System Notices, but *push* mirror failures do not appear to be listed.

Without going into the settings of each repo manually, can I find out which repos have a mirror setup to push to GitHub? Can I view which push mirror syncs have failed?

I have full access to Gitea, the server, and the database (PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

With access to the server and with Gitea setup as a systemd service (called `gitea.service` below) you can check the service logs.

`sudo journalctl -fu gitea.service --since "1 day ago" > gitea-log`

Then search these for the message logged when Gitea fails to authenticate when pushing a mirror:

`grep 'Authentication failed' gitea-log`

The default sync is 8 hours, so you can tweak the first command, depending upon if you use the default or something else.